# flask socketio - server does not reload or update

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I'm trying to use flask-socketio. I ran a simple example from the docs and it worked fine. I'm using a virtual environment

## app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    print('received message: ' + message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, port=8000)
```

and in `demo.py` I use the socketio client library

## demo.py

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace

def on_message_response(*args):
    print('on_message_response', args)

with SocketIO('localhost', 8000, LoggingNamespace) as socketIO:
    socketIO.emit('message', 'xxx', on_message_response)
    socketIO.wait_for_callbacks(seconds=1)
```

I've installed `eventlet` and this basic example worked fine. When I ran I got the output
 `received message: xxx`
 However when I updated the `app.py` file and `demo.py` to this

## app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(name, age):
    print('We Welcome {} who is {} years old'.format(name,age))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, port=8000)
```

## demo.py

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace

def on_message_response(*args):
   print('on_message_response', args)


with SocketIO('localhost', 8000, LoggingNamespace) as socketIO:
    socketIO.emit('message', {'name':'Dipanshu', 'age':25}, on_message_response)
    socketIO.wait_for_callbacks(seconds=1)
```

It doesnt seem like the app.py reloads or is updating because I keep getting this

> File "app.py", line 10, in handle_message
>       print('received message: ' + message) TypeError: must be str, not dict

I have restarted the `app.py` a few times but I get the same error. I also tried uninstalling `eventlet` and ran it using the Flask server like other Flask app but it was still the same.

Comment: Have you deleted your old `def handle_message(message)` function?

Comment: I updated the `handle_message` with the below mentioned function so yes.

Comment: That's weird. Can you post entire content of `app.py`?

Comment: I just added it. Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Is there any chance the new code hasn't been saved to disk? You can check it by running `cat app.py` to check its content.

Comment: I'm using windows so I can't get `cat` to run. But I don't see how that would be possible because I have obviously saved the file, just like I would any other file .Although I'm doubtful but could it have to do something with me using a virtual env?

Comment: You were right. It appears that the contents are in fact not being saved on the disk, I exited the virtual env and opened the file in another text editor, and it didn't show the updated content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162673/discussion-between-dipanshu-juneja-and-dvnguyen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be an issue with compiled Python files. I'm going to give you a couple of ideas to try:

- My first suggestion is for you to delete all `*.pyc` files and `__pycache__` directories that you have in your main application directory or in any sub-directories. This is going to remove all compiled Python files, and will force Python to recompile everything.
- Alternatively, you can also take your two source files and move them to a brand new directory, and then run your server and client from the new directory. This should also clear any issues due to caching of compiled Python files.

Hope this helps!